# Applying "let" in scheme?

Tags: scheme, interpreter, let

I am trying to write an interpreter for scheme. So far i implemented define, if and some arithmetic expressions. Here is the grammar for my interpreter:

```
<s6> -> <expr>
        | <define>

<expr> -> NUMBER
          | IDENT
          | <if>
          | <let>

<define> -> ( define IDENT <expr> )

<if> -> ( if <expr> <expr> <expr> )

<let> -> ( let ( <var_binding_list> ) <expr> )

<var_binding_list> -> ( IDENT <expr> ) <var_binding_list>
                      | ( IDENT <expr> )
```

Here is the code i have written so far:

```
(define get-operator (lambda (op-symbol)
(cond
    ((equal? op-symbol '+) +)
    ((equal? op-symbol '-) -)
    ((equal? op-symbol '*) *)
    ((equal? op-symbol '/) /)
    (else (error "s6-interpret: operator not implemented -->" op-symbol)))))

(define let-stmt? (lambda (e)
(and (list? e) (equal? (car e) 'let) (= (length e) 3))))

(define if-stmt? (lambda (e)
(and (list? e) (equal? (car e) 'if) (= (length e) 4))))

(define define-stmt? (lambda (e)
(and (list? e) (equal? (car e) 'define) (symbol? (cadr e)) (= (length e) 3))))


(define get-value (lambda (var env)
(cond
    ((null? env) (error "s6-interpret: unbound variable -->" var))
    ((equal? (caar env) var) (cdar env))
    (else (get-value var (cdr env))))))


(define extend-env (lambda (var val old-env)
(cons (cons var val) old-env)))


(define repl (lambda (env)
(let* (
    (dummy1 (display "cs305> "))
    (expr (read))
    (new-env (if (define-stmt? expr)
                (extend-env (cadr expr) (s6-interpret (caddr expr) env) env)env))
    (val (if (define-stmt? expr)
                (cadr expr)
                (s6-interpret expr env)))
    (dummy2 (display "cs305: "))
    (dummy3 (display val))
    (dummy4 (newline))
    (dummy4 (newline)))
(repl new-env))))


(define s6-interpret (lambda (e env)
(cond
    ((number? e) e)
    ((symbol? e) (get-value e env))
    ((not (list? e)) (error "s6-interpret: cannot evaluate -->" e))
    ((if-stmt? e) (if (eq? (cadr e) 0) ( s6-interpret (cadddr e) env) ( s6-interpret(caddr e) env)))
    ((let-stmt? e) (apply let (map s6-interpret (cdr e))))
    (else
        (let ((operands (map s6-interpret (cdr e) (make-list (length (cdr e)) env)))
                (operator (get-operator (car e))))
            (apply operator operands))))))


(define cs305-interpreter (lambda () (repl '())))
```

Everything i have written except "let" works fine. let-stmt? procedure also works as i want but the part of the code ((let-stmt? e) (apply let (map s6-interpret (cdr e)))) in s6-interpret does not work fine, it gives me an error saying that "syntactic keyword may not be used as an expression". Can anyone help me with the implementation of the interpreter for "let" statement as given in the grammar?

Thank you

Comment: Can you repost after you get the above to compile and run w/o an argument count error?

Comment: @GoZoner well, actually i am still thinking about how to implement let statement, i could not solve it. You mean reposting after solving it?

Comment: Just like you cannot apply if you cannot apply let. let is actually just syntactic sugar for a anonymous procedure so you should  implement lambda-calls first, like ((lambda (x) x) 5) should evaluate to 5. Then you can implement so that (let ((x 5)) x) is synonymous to that.

Comment: You shouldn't implement `let` _before_ implementing `lambda`. `let` is not a normal form, it's a derived expression that after a syntactical transformation gets evaluated as a `lambda`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to implement `let` without worrying about `lambda` as `let` just extends the environment and evaluates the body in the newly extended environment.  As so:

```
...
((let-stmt? e)
 (let ((names (map car  (cadr e)))
       (inits (map cadr (cadr e))))
   ;; Evaluate inits in env
   (let ((vals (map (lambda (init) (s6-interpret init env)) inits)))
     ;; Extend env with names+vals
     (let ((new-env (append (map cons names vals) env)))
       ;; Eval body in new env
       (s6-interpret (caddr e) new-env)))))   ; assumes 'body' is one form...
...
```

You also get to avoid worrying about general function calls using this approach.

Comment: well thank you, i am trying to understand it now, but i am not sure whether it evaluates to 7 when i write (let ((x 3) (y 4)) (+ x y)). Does it? For now it looks to me that we are assigning values to variables, but do we also calculate the expression here after assigning values?

Comment: I tried the input (let ((x 4) (y 3)) (+ x y)) but it gave an error saying that operator not implemented (+ x y). Can we do anything about this? Thanks

Comment: You asked 'do we also calculate the expression here'.  Perhaps you can look for where `s6-interpret` is called since, as you know, that is where stuff is calculated.

Answer (score 4):

You can't `apply` the special form `let`. The error is clear: it's not a procedure, it's syntax (a macro). One possible solution would be to implement a syntactic transformation at the evaluator level, once a `let` is detected, transform it into a `lambda` expression and evaluate it.

Take a look at exercise 4.6 in [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.2), look for the topic "Derived Expressions". The key idea here is that if you find an expression such as this one:

```
(let ((x 1)
      (y 2))
  (+ x y))
```

You must transform it into this expression, that can be easily evaluated:

```
((lambda (x y)
   (+ x y))
 1 2)
```